# How to select multiple file by using Auto it for selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, autoit

I have created an autoit .exe for selecting single file which will serve upload functionality by using webdriver.

but, I need to upload files in 100s , so I can not execute that one file select auto it code.
Now, I need to write a code in auto-it which will select all files present in a particular folder(folder browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send( "^a" ) try this hope this may help

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+A by using the Code in AutoIt Script Editor. This may work.

Comment: I tried to do so, but, was not able to
Can you please post me the snippet of code?